Is it true or false that $\mathcal R([0,1])=\mathcal R_\alpha([0,1])$, where $\alpha$ is continuous?
Let $\alpha:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a monotonically increasing continuous function. Let $\mathcal R_\alpha([0,1])$ be a set of all functions that are Riemann–Stieltjes integrable on $[0,1]$ with respect to $\alpha$, and $\mathcal R([0,1])$ is a set of Riemann integrable functions on $[0,1]$.
Is it true or false that $\mathcal R([0,1])=\mathcal R_\alpha([0,1])$?
I think the answer is yes because when $f$ is Riemann integrable (or Riemann-Stieltjes integrable), it either has finite or countably many discontinuities, and continuity of $\alpha$ will cover all these discontinuities... I am not sure how to argue rigorously.
I also think the answer might be no because $\alpha$ might not be Lipschitz.

If you allow weakly increasing functions, then consider constant $\alpha$ and see what happens.
